# Netbeans - Expired certificate on ftp connection

Tags: ssl, netbeans, ftp

I'm using Netbeans with automatic upload to server each time I save a file locally. I suddenly started running into this error:

```
Cannot connect to server xxx.xxx.xxx
(Cause: java.security.cert.CertificateExpiredException: NotAfter: Sat May 30 12:34:56 CEST 2020)
```

I've checked my server (running Apache with cPanel/WHM on AWS EC2), and all SSL certificates seem to be updated and valid. I can connect to the same server using FileZilla. I'm using FTP with explicit TLS in both FileZilla and NetBeans.

I first got this error on my legacy Netbeans 8.2 installation, so I tried updating to 11.2, but I get the same error. Possibly because it duplicated my settings from 8.2?

(If I connect without encryption, it works.)

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully my own experience with that issue helps you along, though I have not fixed it for myself, yet.

It seems, that not the server's certificate is invalid, but the root-certificate against which it is checked by the java-JRE has expired. see https://www.ssl.com/blogs/addtrust-external-ca-root-expired-may-30-2020/  - These root-certificates are normally stored locally with the OS. But some applications come with their own keystore.

And since JRE apparently does not use the OS's certificate store, this might explain FileZilla behaving differently.

I tried updating my local Java-installation to no avail. I also tried to find the out-of-date root-certificate in the Java-config. And indeed, it is listed with the "appropriate" valid-until date. But temporarily removing it, did not help. No luck there, either.

Comment: Interesting! I've temporarily disabled tls in the hopes that an answer here or a program update would solve the problem.